# PyInstaller и вечные мучения. Почему вылезает ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Скомпилил .py в .exe через pyinstaller
пишет `local variable referenced before assigment`
хотя в **.py и .py.exe** всё работает
Что делать, как быть?

код

```
import requests as rq
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import os
import time
import zipfile
import wget
import shutil

def show_message():
    
    loginreq = rq.post("https://www.kooft.site/login/", data={'n':name.get(),'pwd':pwd.get()})
    if 'Неверный пароль' in loginreq.text:
        messagebox.showerror(" f ", "Не удалось войти в аккаунт")
    else:
        file = open('gamedo.txt', 'w')
        f = file.write(name.get() + '/' + pwd.get())
        messagebox.showinfo(" Успешный вход ", "Перезапустите GameDo")
 

root = Tk()
root.title("gd")
root.geometry("300x250")

file = open('gamedo.txt', 'r')
f = file.read()
if not f:
    name = StringVar()
    pwd = StringVar()

    name_label = Label(text="Введите логин и пароль от аккаунта")
    name_label.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="w")

    name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
    name_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c")


    pwd_entry = Entry(textvariable=pwd)
    pwd_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c")


    message_button = Button(text="Click Me", command=show_message)
    message_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
else:
    n = f.split('/')[0]
    pwd = f.split('/')[1]
    messagebox.showinfo("logged in", f[0])
    qreq = rq.post('https://www.kooft.site/checkgames/', data={'user':f.split('/')[0]})

    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.grid()
    combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame,values = qreq.text.split(',') ,height=3)
    combobox.set(qreq.text.split(',')[0])
    combobox.grid(column=0,row=0)
    def play():
        try:
            
            game = qreq.text.split(',')[combobox.current()].replace("'", "") 
            if qreq.text.split(',')[combobox.current()] in qreq.text.split(',') and os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+game ):
                 
                 print(game)
                 vnew = rq.post('https://www.kooft.site/gamev', data={'game':game}).text
                 vnow = open(game+'/version.txt', 'r').read()
            if vnew == vnow:
                pts = os.getcwd()+os.getcwd()[2]+game+os.getcwd()[2]+"Windows"+os.getcwd()[2]+game+".exe"
                os.startfile(pts)
            else:
                shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd()+os.getcwd()[2]+game, ignore_errors=True)
                dl = wget.download("http://f0299148.xsph.ru/"+game+".zip", os.getcwd() )
                print(dl)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('download it')
            wget.download("http://f0299148.xsph.ru/"+game+".zip", os.getcwd() )
            print('dload')
            os.makedirs(os.getcwd()+os.getcwd()[2]+game)
            ex = zipfile.ZipFile(os.getcwd()+os.getcwd()[2]+game+".zip", 'r')
            ex.extractall(os.getcwd()+os.getcwd()[2]+game)
            ex.close()
            
            
            
    
    message_button = Button(text="Play", command=play)
    message_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

    
        
        



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Похоже у вас где-то в коде `local variable referenced before assigment`. Можете скинуть код?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, вставил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

```py
if qreq.text.split(',')[combobox.current()] in qreq.text.split(',') and 
    os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+game ):
    print(game)
    vnew = rq.post('https://www.kooft.site/gamev', data={'game':game}).text
    vnow = open(game+'/version.txt', 'r').read()
if vnew == vnow: # vnew и vnow объявлены в другом блоке кода и недоступны здесь
    #...
```

2. 

```py
try:
    game = qreq.text.split(',')[combobox.current()].replace("'", "") 
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('download it')
                                  # то же самое с переменной game
    wget.download("http://f0299148.xsph.ru/"+game+".zip", os.getcwd())
```